# Getting error "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found" while uploading the file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, multipart

I have tried to upload the file in `jmeter`:

Please find below mentioned details which i passed in request,

Http reuest:

```
POST: http:${server_name}/attachment
```

`1.File Path : D:\localdrive\test_docs\images.jpg 
 2.Parameter Name:images.jpg
 3.MIME Type:image/jpg`

Http Header :

```
1.Accept :  / ,
2.Content-Type :    multipart/form-data
```

Response Data :

```
 {"response":"the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"}
```

could anyone please share the solution on the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it !!!

Make sure that below parameter should be mentioned in HTTP request.

1. Implementation should be HttpClient3.1 or Java (Don't keep it blank)
2. Content encoding :UTF-8
3. "Use multipart/form-data for Post" in HTTP sample should be checked.
4. In HTTP header (Content-Type : multipart/form-data)
5. for Parameter-name & MIME-type
   e.g. In browser enter F12 & hit the request ,
     refer the content in Network tab :
     Inside Param u will get request param 
   for example if param is :
   HTML contains= Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="images.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg

Then Parameter-name :file  & MIME-type :image/jpeg  should be like this.

& now its work fine ,That's a great relief for me !!!

also thanks Anders for ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a checkbox inside the sampler which uploads the file that says "Use multipart/form-data for Post" which *needs* to be checked.
- If your HTML looks something like this `input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser"/>"` your parameter name must be `"dataFile"` which is the name of the input file field.
- You can also use a sniffer tool like fiddler for example or the HTTP/S script recorder JMeter has to capture the request and check the `MIME Type` for example because I'm not sure if jpg files are `"image/jpg" MIME Type`

Make sure those are correctly formatted and check out what BlazeMeter says about [uploading files](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

- HTML contains= 
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
  filename="images.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
  So i have set =
  Parameter-name :file  MIME-type :image/jpeg ; In sample request i have already checked "Use multipart/form-data for Post" which i have not mentioned early.

Then also its not work ...
anything else which i missed here

Comment: getting same response :{"response":"the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

& Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request