# How to send text file to a http request which shows error "request was rejected because no multipart boundary as found"

Tags: java, automation, jmeter, httprequest, multipartform-data

I am having some issue in file uploading with jmeter

I hav added the parameter in http header manager and uploaded .txt file and I am hitting a http request.

[image: Parameters]

Sampler Request giving **request code 200**

Response data is shown below:

> Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was founderror

Comment: Possibly a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021448/getting-error-the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found

Comment: @aschoerk I hav already tried the solution But It did'nt worked out.

Comment: Have you tried not sending Content-Type ?

Comment: @user7294900  I am gettinng response code 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you provide full path to the file being uploaded under "Files Upload" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Make sure you tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box
3. Make sure "Parameter Name" matches the "name" attribute of the relevant [File HTML Input field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

   [image: JMeter File Upload]

---

In the absolute majority of cases it is much easier to just record your file upload event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just make sure you copy your file(s) to JMeter's "bin" folder prior to recording the request itself, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved.

1. Add **Http cookie manager**
2. Add all parameters inside parameters section of http request
3. Add file mime type text/plain

Thanks everyone for your support.